# Do I really need to specific the generics type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say we have the following function:

```js
function aBoringFunction<T>(someBoringValue: T) {
  console.log(someBoringValue);
}
```

Is there any difference with the following calls?

```js
aBoringFunction<number>(123456);

aBoringFunction("Hello, world!");
```

And yeah, I can imagine the first call is necessary for generics variable inside the function

```
function aBoringFunction<T>(someBoringValue: T) {

  const whaaat: T | null = null;

  console.log(someBoringValue);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `aBoringFunction(123456);`? The compiler can infer that `123456` is a number.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the function more often than not you do not need to specify the type (like `aBoringFunction<number>(123456)`) because typescript will infer it based on the type of the variable that you pass in:

```
// No need to specify `number`
aBoringFunction(123456);
```

Sometimes you actually want to specify it manually to avoid passing the wrong type. That's because type `T` is unbounded, so you can pass any type of value and it will always be accepted.

If you want to restrict the type `T`, then you should use `extends`:

```
// Only types that extend `string` are allowed
function aBoringFunction<T extends string>(someBoringValue: T)
```

Generics are useful when you want to avoid copy multiple functions that do the same thing but with different types:

```
function append<T>(array: T[], element: T) {
  return [...array, element];
}

// Instead of 
function appendNumber(array: number[], element: number) {
  return [...array, element];
}

function appendString(array: string[], element: string) {
  return [...array, element];
}
```